# Can somebody explain the results for the nvidia-smi command in a terminal?

Tags: 18.04, nvidia

I run `lspci | grep -i nvidia` and got this 
`01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX110] (rev a2)`
I run `nvidia-smi` and got this output. What does the output mean?

```
(base)  ahmad@ahmad-anis  ~  nvidia-smi
Thu Mar 26 07:53:32 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX110       Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   43C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    164MiB /  2004MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1488      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            76MiB |
|    0      1697      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          47MiB |
|    0     13350      G   ...AAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAA --shared-files    38MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead; https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @muru sorry will be careful next time

Comment: You can update this post.

Comment: @muru Done update

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your screenshot:

[image]

Indicates you have a [PCI Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI) identified as 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation and its details. Which mostly means you have a [GPU or Video Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) (You Lucky Guy!)

The second part of your screenshot shows the results of `nvidia-smi`, from the developer's manpage:

[image]

> nvidia-smi (also NVSMI) provides monitoring and management
>   capabilities       for each of NVIDIA's Tesla, Quadro, GRID and
>   GeForce devices from Fermi       and higher architecture families.
>   GeForce Titan series devices are sup-       ported for most functions
>   with very limited  information  provided  for       the  remainder  of
>   the  Geforce brand.  NVSMI is a cross platform tool       that
>   supports all standard NVIDIA driver-supported  Linux  distros,  as
>   well as 64bit versions of Windows starting with Windows Server 2008
>   R2.       Metrics can be consumed directly by users via stdout,  or 
>   provided  by       file via CSV and XML formats for scripting
>   purposes.

From the developer: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DCGM/docs/nvidia-smi-367.38.pdf

If you need information for a specific part of this data, you may wish to edit your question and add the specific information for what you wish an answer.

BTW: Reading the manual may provide a lot of useful help.

Comment: Specifically, the `...AAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAA --shared-files` item is from Chromium. When running deep learning trainings on my GPU, I uncheck the hardware acceleration option in chrome://settings which frees up ~200-300 MB of GPU memory

Comment: Sounds great but... How is the hardware acceleration working after disabling? Did you miss something by having it disabled? Interesting.

Comment: Mine is gone from the list after disabling - I was just mentioning for other people who might be wondering how to free up the memory from that line item